# Generator of a transport semigroup on the torus

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, dynamical-systems, semigroup-of-operators

Consider on the Banach space $C( \mathbb T;\mathbb R)$ of continuous
functions on the 1-dimensional torus $\mathbb T:=\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$
(equipped with uniform norm) the operator $L$ given by

$$ L f (x)   =  b(x) f '(x) $$

with domain  $D(L) := C^1(\mathbb T;\mathbb R)$. We assume here $b\in C^1(\mathbb T;\mathbb R)$.

In the case $b(x)\neq 0$ for every $x$, we have that $L$ is closed 
(use theorem for exchanging uniform convergence and derivation) and generates 
a strongly continuous semigroup $T_t$ on $C(\mathbb T;\mathbb R)$
(by using that $b(x)  f'(x) -f(x) = g(x)$ has a $C^1$ solution $f$  for every continuous $g$).

In general ($b(x)$ possibly having zeros) $(L,D(L))$ is no longer closed. 
 Does its closure still generate a strongly continuous semigroup?
 (In case, can I characterise the domain of the closure more explicitly?)